# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined node js

Tags: node.js, express

I have the file submission form on the index.html file. When the file selected, i need to say 'file uploaded', else need to display 'please upload the file'

**app.js**

```
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const http = require("http").Server(app).listen(3000);

    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(express.json());

    console.log("Server Started");

    app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    }
    )

    app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    if (req.files) {

        console.log(req.files);
        const file = req.files.filename;
        const filename = file.name;

        if (!filename) {
        res.send("Please select the file to upload");
        }
        else {
        res.send("uploaded");
        }
    }
    })
```

**index.html**

```
    <div>
    <h1 style="align-content: center">Upload your file here!</h1>
    </div>
    <div >

    <form label="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
        <label> Enter reference</label>
        <input type="text" name="test_text"></input>
        <br><br>
        <input type="file" name="filename">
        <input type="submit" value="upload">
    </form>
    </div>
```

**Error message:**

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>     at C:\Users\Desktop\LocalGithub\uploadFileLocal-express-fileupload\app.js:24:27
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is quoted from express docs:

> In Express 4, req.files is no longer available on the req object by default. To access uploaded files on the req.files object, use multipart-handling middleware like busboy, multer, formidable, multiparty, connect-multiparty, or pez.

As it said, I suggest you to use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) since it's more popular and easy to use

**EDIT:**

If you are using "express-fileupload" middleware, you have to load it via `.use()` method:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http").Server(app).listen(3000);
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
^^^^^

app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());

app.use(fileUpload({
^^^
    useTempFiles : true,
    tempFileDir : '/tmp/'
}));

...
```

check the [docs](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload) for more details:

Comment: I am using express-fileupload instead of multer! How we can parse the filename?

Comment: If you see my original post, I have already included below two lines to access the response parameters. app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());

Comment: I have added index.html file as well. Please check!

Comment: @Nandy `urlencoded` and `json` middlewares has nothing to do with `fileUpload`, it's a different package that let you upload files, so you need load it separately. I added arrows `^` to my answer to indicate where to make changes in your code

Answer (score 0):

Please try replace `file.name` with `req.files[0].originalname`.

Comment: Sorry, this is not helping. Any other ideas please ?

Answer (score 0):

You did not create the object for which attribute name is defined.
object: ***req.files.filename***, attribute: ***req.files.filename.name*** should work fine.
Your code should be like this:

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    if (req.files.filename) {   //missing filename

        console.log(req.files.filename); //missing filename
        const file = req.files.filename;
        const filename = file.name;
  ...
});
```